# HttpClient does not decrypt HTTPS without Fiddler

Tags: c#, https, httpclient, fiddler

I am not sure if my question is correct, but I couldn't find any relevant information. I am assuming that HttpClient is supposed to decrypt HTTPS responses automatically, but for some reason, it doesn't, except when the Fiddler is running.

```
HttpClient Client;
HttpResponseMessage response;

using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.google.com/"))
{
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));

    response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

string sResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Log(sResponse); // "\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\u0002��i{۸�0��\u007f\u0005͜c�c�\u0016" etc.
```

I tried to disable all https-related options in Fiddler and resetting IE proxy options, but it seems not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out I had the wrong Accept-Encoding header:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

**EDIT:**

You CAN use "gzip, deflate" encoding, but you have to specify decompression method in your *HttpClientHandler*:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Haha I can't believe I overlooked this. I assumed AutomaticDecompression would be enabled by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the `request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");`
then the response ll not be encoded.